# pandas.read_csv() using url - file location

Tags: python, pandas

I am using below code in jupyter notebook to read csv from url.

`df_train = pd.read_csv('https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/train.csv')`

Any idea where the csv file gets saved on drive?

Comment: Works fine for me, what is the actual issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if it gets saved except you download it or you can write df_train to a .csv with:

```
df_train.to_csv('train.csv')
```

This will be saved in your present working directory.